# Cant recieve GCM notification after killing my android app

Tags: java, android

After killing app if i sent message from one device to another the GCM will not works.

It gives the following Error:

```
W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.cabipool (has extras) }
```

Comment: it is not possible.....check the logs in GCM broadcast receiver..

Answer (score 0):

In your Broadcast receiver ,

add this at the end.

```
setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

It will solve the issue.

Comment: @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GCMPushReceiverService.class.getName());
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }catch(Exception e){

            Log.d("Error", "error en C2DM" + e.toString());
        }
    }
}

Comment: I am getting thesein logcat

Comment: W/ctxmgr: [AclManager]checkPermissionTypeStatus: no inject permission for { uid=10012, packageName=com.google.android.gms }. Returned permission was: PACKAGE_NOT_WHITELISTED for context name=POWER_CONNECTION, account=account#-517948760#